# Understanding how to compute $5^{15}\pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Compute $5^{15} \pmod 7$.

Can someone help me understand how to solve this? I know there is a trick, but my professor did not completely explain it in class and I'm stuck.

Comment: Lots of tricks. Was Fermat's Theorem mentioned? Or else note that $2^3\equiv 1$, so $2^{15}\equiv 1$. But $5\equiv -2$, so $5^{15}\equiv -1$. With such small numbers, we don't even need tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know 7 is prime and 7 does not divide 5 so you can use Fermats Little Theorm to get $5^6\equiv1 (mod 7)$ $\Rightarrow$ $5^{15} \equiv 5^3 (mod 7)$ 
then you can do $ (25)(5)\equiv (-4)(2) (mod7) $ then $  -8 \equiv 6 (mod 7)$ $\Rightarrow $ $5^{15} \equiv 6 (mod 7)$ hence $5^{15}$ Modulo 7 is 6

Answer (score 0):

$5^3=125, 5^3= 2$ mod 7, $5^3*5^3= 2*2$ mod 7, so $5^{15}=2^5$ mod 7=1 mod 7. sorry about the equivalent sign, i don't remember the code.

Comment: for congruence one would write (enclosed in dollar signs) a\equiv b\pmod{c}. And $125\equiv -1\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pattern of $5^n$ mod $7$: $5,4,1,5,4,1...$ the $15$th number in this pattern is $1$.